# Align radio buttons horizontally in django forms

Tags: django, forms, radio-button, alignment

HI

I want to align the radio buttons horizontally. By default django forms displays in vertical format.

```
feature_type  = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices = formfields.FeatureType, widget = forms.RadioSelect)
```

Is there any special parameter that we can pass for radio buttons alignment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is more of a CSS problem than Django. You can perhaps add a class to the radio buttons and say float:left; in your css for radio button class.

Comment: I have googled it and I have found one link where I could not able to make it work. https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/~bm6432/Django-Modifying+RadioSelect+Widget+to+have+horizontal+buttons. I will try to add the css and will let you know if it fixes. thanks geekam

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thats the behavior of the `RadioField`. If you want it rendered horizontally, create a horizontal renderer, like something as follows:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class HorizontalRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
  def render(self):
    return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))


class ApprovalForm(forms.Form):
    approval = forms.ChoiceField(choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES,
                 initial=0,
                 widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer),
                                 )
```

Comment: Hey lakshman, when I execute the above code its getting error `mark_safe` is not defined. If you can help this that would be agreat help

Comment: You should import that from Django.templates

Comment: Cool its working fine laxman. Thanks for the help :-) for mark_safe to work I have imported: `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`

Comment: Since Django 1.11, this gives me an error at ``forms.RadioSelect.renderer``: "type object 'RadioSelect' has no attribute 'renderer'".

Comment: I got the same error   "type object 'RadioSelect' has no attribute 'renderer'" .any help please

Comment: this does not work in newer versions of Django and it isn't the right way to go anyway. Check out the answer below that changes the styling of ul -> li which should be selected as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another way out is to changing the style of ul->li list to display:inline-block. You can do something like that

```
 <style>
 ul#youelementId li{
  display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
```

hope this would help next reader.

Comment: the only way that worked for me in Django 3.1.4

Answer (score 6):

I've come up with an alternative solution. If you are using bootstrap to render your forms, you can add the .form-check-inline class to the input and the field will display horizontally. Listed below is code that shows what I'm describing. I hope this helps someone from reinventing the wheel. Thanks for reading. Take care and have a good day.

```
                feature_type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                required=False,
                ...
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-check-inline'})
                )
```

[image: This image shows a set of radio buttons displayed horizontally.]

Comment: This is a very nice and clean solution.

Comment: What's the necessity to turn `required` off (=False)?

Comment: this is for checkboxes, and the OP asked re: Radio Buttons -- does it work for those as well, or only with CheckboxSelectMultiple?

Comment: I tried this with Django 4.2 and bootstrap 5. I does not work. The check boxes are still aligned vertically.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why people suggest so difficult decisions, that don'ts work for my Django 4.1 xD. Solution:

```
{% for choice in form.feature_type %}
    {{ choice }}
{% endfor %}

# Also you can use:
{{ choice.tag }}
{{ choice.choice_label }}
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Django 2.2.6 above solutions did not worked well, so I post my solution after many tries and following the breadcrumbs until the django forms widget templates used.

I had to override 2 templates, and heritage my own widget class and then point it.

The modified default django templates have been:

- django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/input_option.html
- django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/multiple_input.html

Now they are:

PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_APP/templates/admin/horizontal_option.html

```
{% if widget.wrap_label %}<label{% if widget.attrs.id %} for="{{ widget.attrs.id }}"{% endif %} class="radio-inline">{% endif %}{% include "django/forms/widgets/input.html" %}{% if widget.wrap_label %} {{ widget.label }}</label>{% endif %}
```

PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_APP/templates/admin/horizontal_radios.html

```
{% with id=widget.attrs.id %}<ul{% if id %} id="{{ id }}"{% endif %}{% if widget.attrs.class %} class="{{ widget.attrs.class }}"{% endif %}>{% for group, options, index in widget.optgroups %}{% if group %}
  <li>{{ group }}
    <ul{% if id %} id="{{ id }}_{{ index }}"{% endif %}>{% endif %}{% for option in options %}
    {% include option.template_name with widget=option %}{% endfor %}{% if group %}
  </ul></li>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
</ul>{% endwith %}
```

- The first one includes a hardcoded class: `class="radio-inline"` at labels, which in default Django had nothing
- The second one the rendering of the set of radios, I removed the extra HTML li tags they were rendered inside the internal ul tag.

Then you need to create your own widget class:

```
from django.forms import RadioSelect


class HorizontalRadioSelect(RadioSelect):
    template_name = 'admin/horizontal_radios.html'
    option_template_name = 'admin/horizontal_inputs.html'
```

And finally, in my case, I pointed to it overriding `formfield_overrides` class attribute in my admin. But you can do this in your models too I think:

```
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.BooleanField: {'widget': HorizontalRadioSelect(choices=[(True, "Yes"), (False, "No"), (None, "Unknown")],)},
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for versions Django 2.0+ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding this for those using `django-crispy-forms` and rendering fields with `|as_crispy_field`.  None of the solutions above worked for me, but this did:

Assuming you have something like this in your form:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['your_field_name']

    your_field_name = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=YOUR_CHOICE_LIST)
```

...and this in your template:

```
<div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ form.your_field_name|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The following CSS does the trick:

```
<style>
    #div_id_your_field_name div {
        display:inline-flex;
        width: 100%;
    } /* Renders the radio buttons inline and spreads across your div */
    
    #div_id_your_field_name .form-check-label {
        margin-left: 10px;

    } /* puts a bit of space between the radio and label */
    
    #div_id_your_field_name .form-label {
        display: none;

    } /* Optional, if you want to suppress the default label for some reason */
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, this worked (unlike every other solution presented on this page -- I assume because I'm using Crispy Forms)

Comment: This is probably the reason, yes.  Glad it helped!  (And best wishes on the career transition - you won't regret it!)

Answer (score 1):

In forms.py for your field make widget with attr class="inline"

```
widgets ='your_name': forms.RadioSelect(choices=your_CHOICES,attrs={"class": "inline"})
```

In CSS make this class inline-block

```
.inline div{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modified forms.RadioSelect:**

```
class HorizontalRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        css_style = 'style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;"'

        self.renderer.inner_html = '<li ' + css_style + '>{choice_value}{sub_widgets}</li>'
```

Working with on the Python 3.4 with the standart admin of the Django 1.10 
[image]

and the Django-Suit(http://djangosuit.com/) (it use Bootstrap`s 2 styles)

[image]

*Not tested for the Django-grappelli, yet.*

Comment: This answer isn't directly applicable to the example code provided by the user and, as such, doesn't answer their question.

Comment: On Django 4.2 (and possibly before), this says, `'HorizontalRadioSelect' object has no attribute 'renderer'`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#widget) 'attrs' is a dictionary containing HTML attributes to be set on the rendered widget.

With that in mind a simple form based solution would be something like the following:

```
feature_type  = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    choices = formfields.FeatureType,
    widget = forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
        'style': 'display: inline-block'
    })
)
```

Comment: There is no "display" attribute, this should be `"style": "display: inline-block"` and it will not work this way. `display: inline-block` will be applied to the radio button instead of `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no need to override the widget, template or anything else in admin. At least since 2008 (see [forms.css](https://github.com/django/django/blame/41725602afebe2ddb018b99afe134384cc3bf69e/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/forms.css#L54)), the easiest way is to pass a class attribute `inline`: `attrs={'class': 'inline'}`

In a custom form, it may look like:

```py
field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('1', 'one'), ('2', 'two')),
                          widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'inline'}))
```

… and it works the very same for checkboxes:

```py
field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('1', 'one'), ('2', 'two')),
                                  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'inline'}))
```

And it should be the very same for formfield overrides, either via ModelAdmin `formfield_overrides` or `formfield_for_*` functions.

Comment: This does not work for me, applying the attrs dict with class: inline has no effect on either RadioSelect nor CheckboxSelectMultiple.

Answer (score 0):

as renerer raise this error for me:

> AttributeError: type object 'RadioSelect' has no attribute 'renderer'

I come up with this code:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in form %}
        <p>{{ question.label }}: </p>
        {% for choice in question %}
            {{ choice }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit">
            submit
    </button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach. In my opinion, it is the simplest

```
class YourAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.YourModel
        widgets = {
            "your_field": forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"class": "inline"}),
        }
```

or just define your field something like this

```
    your_field = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=(...),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"class": "inline"}),
    )
```

Comment: tried this exactly as shown, the radio select buttons remain stacked vertically. the attrs dict is being ignored, and I have yet to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure this out for a CMS I manage. Some of the answers here are close, but aren't completely right. You need to provide the `class` in the `attrs` parameter, as at least one other response has mentioned, but you should provide `inline li`. If you provide `style`, then the style will get applied to the the `input` element, instead of the `li`.

I couldn't find anything in their documentation that lists the available CSS classes for their components, so I discovered this by using DevTools in Firefox to look at the available styles, and then finding `inline li` in their `forms.css`.

This solution makes it possible change the alignment without needing to mess with templates or making my own CSS file.

```py
from django import forms

from .models import MyModel

MyForm = forms.modelform_factory(
    MyModel,
    widgets={"field_name": forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"class": "inline li"})},
    fields="__all__",
)
```

To figure out what other classes are available so you can more conveniently modify the the layout of various form elements, run `python manage.py collectstatic` (make sure `STATIC_ROOT` is defined), and you can find `forms.css` under `STATIC_ROOT/static/admin/css`.

In this particular repo, I have `STATIC_ROOT` set to `./lib` in my local_settings.py:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic

1408 static files copied to './lib/static'.

$ ls -1 lib/static/admin/css/
autocomplete.css
base.css
changelists.css
dashboard.css
fonts.css
forms.css
login.css
nav_sidebar.css
responsive.css
responsive_rtl.css
rtl.css
vendor/
widgets.css
```

Once I actually got it displaying horizontally with a clean solution, I also wanted to hide the blank option from the list of choices, so ended up creating my own CSS file to do that, since the documentation for that [was easy to find](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/media/)

```css
/* BASE_DIR/static/css/my_customizations.css */
#id_field_name li:has(input[value='']) {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```py
from django import forms

from .models import MyModel

class MyForm(
    forms.modelform_factory(
        MyModel,
        widgets={"field_name": forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"class": "inline li"})},
        fields="__all__",
    )
):
    class Media:
        css = {"all": ("css/my_customizations.css",)}
```

(Though, as of January 2023, `:has` is not yet supported by Firefox, but will hopefully be supported [sometime this year](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039#c61))