# customize radio buttons in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

template code is

```
{{ form.incident_live }}
```

forms.py

```
INCIDENT_LIVE = (
    ('0', 'Live'),
    ('1', 'Test'),
)
class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):
     incident_live = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),choices=INCIDENT_LIVE)
```

The above code is giving me the radio buttons with choices in vertical order but i want it to be in horizontal i.e the equivalent html would be `<input type="radio" name="status" />Live  <input type="radio" name="status" checked="checked"/> Test`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align radio buttons horizontally in django forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935546/align-radio-buttons-horizontally-in-django-forms)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a custom widget renderer:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class HorizRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    """ this overrides widget method to put radio buttons horizontally
        instead of vertically.
    """
    def render(self):
            """Outputs radios"""
            return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))

class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):
     incident_live = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer),choices=INCIDENT_LIVE)
```

taken from https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/~bm6432/Django-Modifying+RadioSelect+Widget+to+have+horizontal+buttons

Comment: Just not tested it,getting this error "Caught NameError while rendering: global name 'mark_safe' is not defined"

Comment: Oh, sure, added the import statement, give it a try.

Comment: Yes,it is working fine,I accepted your answer.one more hep is it possible to reduce the space between two options, as their is more than 2 inches space between two option,need it to reduce the minimum.

Comment: Suddenly realized that the question was already asked here - marked as duplicate. What if you try smth like this: `mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w.strip() for w in self]))`?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the solution should be quite straight forward. It's all there in Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect).

Here is what I have done in some of the forms:

In the template, where the form fields are being laid out, I will do this:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {% if field.name == "<some_field_name>" %}
    ...
    ...
    {% elif field.name == "<radio_field_name>" %}
        {% for radio in field %}
            <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
                {{ radio.choice_label }}
                <span class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}</span>
            </label>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

The resultant radio selects:

[image]

And this has worked thus far.

Answer (score 2):

This solution of "alecxe" didn't actually worked for me.
But Adding CSS code did work:

```css
{% block style %}
<style>
    .radio{
    display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Nice, this worked perfectly (although I had to do `#key-pic li {display: inline;}`, where `key-pic` is the div-id containing the list.) Not sure why people use the more complex version.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django docs 'attrs' is a dictionary containing HTML attributes to be set on the rendered widget.

With that in mind a simple form based solution would be something like the following:

```
class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    incident_live = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
            'display': 'inline-block',
        }),
        choices=INCIDENT_LIVE
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>

    <style>

        #try li{
        display:inline-block; }

    </style>

<head>

<body>

    <form id="try" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p}}                       
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
              success">Submit</button> 

    </form> 

 </body>
```

Comment: Please comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With inspiration from [user12379095](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61167510/3203246) I came up with this to get the radios to work with Bootstrap. This is for reference for people like me who are ignorant in HTML and CSS. This is using Boostrap 5, Django 3.1.6:

**In forms.py:**

```
from django import forms

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ChoiceField(
        label = 'test',
        choices = zip([1,2,3], ['a','b','c']),
        widget = forms.RadioSelect(
            attrs = {'class' : 'form-check-input'}
        )
    )
```

**In html template:**

```
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {% for radio in field %}
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    {{ radio }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```