# Django 3 - Align Radio Button Horizontally

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have created user signup form in Django3.

In the form I want to have a radio button based choice selection for the user.

The forms.py looks like

```
   class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
   ....
       subscription_choice = (
        ('yearly', 'Yearly'),('monthly', 'Monthly'),
        )

    subscription_type  = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    choices = subscription_choice,
    widget = forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
        "style": "display: inline-block"
    })
```

The model file looks like.

```
class SignUp(AbstractBaseUser):

    subscription_choice = (
        ('yearly', 'Yearly'),('monthly', 'Monthly'),
        )

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=14,primary_key=True)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="None")
    subscription_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="monthly", choices=subscription_choice)
    ....
```

I have tried some css tricks as suggested in some answers on SO but no luck.

The result I am getting is vertical aligned (messy) radio buttons.

[image]

Need some help.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue. I found the solution from JeremyG here [Align radio buttons horizontally in django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935546/align-radio-buttons-horizontally-in-django-forms) worked for me but it requires you to be using bootstrap.

Here is how your code would look.

```
   class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
   ....
       subscription_choice = (
        ('yearly', 'Yearly'),('monthly', 'Monthly'),
        )

    subscription_type  = forms.TypedChoiceField(
    choices = subscription_choice,
    widget = forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
        'class': 'form-check-inline'
    })
```

Alternatively, you can change the style of ul and li in your CSS to something like below in a similar way to Maryam Tariq's answer here [Align radio buttons horizontally in django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935546/align-radio-buttons-horizontally-in-django-forms)

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10%;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

where the key is display: inline-block; I found the other properties useful to make it look how I wanted it.